# is there always exactly one exchange in a broker?

Tags: rabbitmq

In RabbitMQ, regardless of the use case
    patterns (publish-subscribe, message queue, pipeline, RPC, ...)

1. between a producer and its consumer(s),

   - is there always exactly one broker?
   - Does a producer use exactly one exchange, neither more than one exchanges nor not any exchange?
2. Can a broker be used by several independent or related producers and their consumers?

   If yes, do different producers use different exchanges?

I got the above impressions, from the diagrams in:

http://previous.rabbitmq.com/v3_5_7/getstarted.html
[image]

https://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/amqp-concepts.html#amqp-model
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think broker in rabbit mq is a full-fledge messaging processing system (a server that can process messages).

The broker can use many virtual hosts (for example to separate environments, test/dev, etc)

Now you can declare as many exchanges as you want in the broker:

Here is an example using rabbitmq admin:

```
rabbitmqadmin declare exchange name=my-new-exchange type=fanout
```

To get the list of exchanges you can:

```
rabbitmqadmin -V test list exchanges
```

[Here](https://www.rabbitmq.com/management-cli.html) you can find way more operations that can be done with this admin tool

Comment: Thanks. (1) "you can declare as many exchanges as you want in the broker", when is more than one exchanges in a broker used? (2) Can a broker be used by independent producers?  Do different producers use different exchanges? (3)  Is there exactly one exchange for a producer: a producer doesn't use more than one exchanges?

Comment: Thanks for replying. That also helps me clarify my questions. Please see my update to my post.

Comment: 1. Its per usecase, say your application works with a single instance of rabbitmq, and you want to have both pub-sub (all consumers get messages) and queues (consumers "compete" for message handling). Then you'll use different types of exchanges. 2. Producer is a code that sends messages, it always contacts broker to do so (like maintains the connection to it as if a broker is a database server). 3. Yes, producer usually connects to one exchange, but again producer is a code that calls method "send" you can supply any params you want there.